# Explicit cast in c# generic

Tags: c#, generics, casting

The non-generic version of CastRangeAndAdd works fine. If I skip the (object)

```
var castedList = list.Select(e => (NewType)e).ToList();
```

then there is a compile error. If I use the (object) then there is an exception "type TypeHintExcel can not be converted to TypeHint" though the cast operator is there. Any idea? (TypeHint and TypeHintExcel are not related so as I understand the "as keyword" can not be used.)

```
    public static explicit operator TypeHint(TypeHintExcel p)
    {
        var result = new TypeHint()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Hint = p.Hint,
            ExternalType = p.ExternalType,
            AlienType = p.AlienType,
            Weight = p.Weight
        };
        return result;
    }

public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static void CastRangeAndAdd<OldType, NewType>
(this System.Data.Entity.DbSet<NewType> dbCollection, 
        List<OldType> list)
        where NewType : class
    {
        var castedList = list.Select(e => (NewType)(object)e).ToList();
        dbCollection.AddRange(castedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: If probably won't fix your problem, so just a comment, but you never know. But you can simplify your code like this: `var castedList = list.Cast<NewType>().ToList();` This also seems over-eager to convert to a `List<T>` when an `IEnumerable<T>` is likely just as good (and faster).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That will fail for the exact same reason the OP's code fails, as their code is not meaningfully different from `Cast`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write a generic method to do this.  The explicit conversion operation needs to be bound at compile time, but when that method is compiled it has no idea what the source and destination types are, so it can't possibly be bound to your custom conversion operator.

Comment: Thank @Servy. Following your logic list.First().MethodA(); should fail because in complie time we can not know that an OldType object has a MethodA() or not. Then what is point of generics? Or explilicit cast is something special?

Comment: @IstvanHeckl So when you try that code what happens?  Does it work, or does it fail?  The point of generics is to write code that will work *regardless of what type a caller uses in the place of any given generic argument*.  That is, it needs to be *generic*, rather than being *specific*.  For example, `List<T>` is generic because the code for `List<T>` will work *regardless of what type you provide it*.  It can create a list of integers, a list of strings, or a list of `TypeHintExcel ` objects.  It doesn't matter, it will work.

Comment: Can a generic interface constraint help me? The interface might force that MethodA() should exist but I do not see how to enforce that cast must exist between OldType and NewType.

Comment: @IstvanHeckl Indeed there is no way to apply such a constraint.  That's why I said you can't write a generic method to do this.

Comment: Then my logic was wrong. I supposed that at compile time a specific version is created from the generic `CastRangeAndAdd<OldType, NewType>` and then the specific version is checked if it has an appropriate cast operator. Now it seems, the generic version is checked.

Answer (score 0):

c# is not as flexible as c++

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics

C++ allows code that might not be valid for all type parameters in the template, which is then checked for the specific type used as the type parameter. C# requires code in a class to be written in such a way that it will work with any type that satisfies the constraints. For example, in C++ it is possible to write a function that uses the arithmetic operators + and - on objects of the type parameter, which will produce an error at the time of instantiation of the template with a type that does not support these operators. C# disallows this; the only language constructs allowed are those that can be deduced from the constraints.